# check USB debugging is enabled or disabled in android device react native

Tags: android, react-native, usb-debugging

I am working on an android app using react-native. I want to show an alert if USB debugging is enabled in users' devices to turn off the USB debugging option. But I am not able to find a proper library or method to check USB debugging is enabled or disabled in android. I tried `jail-monkey` library but from using this I am only able to find Developer Options is enabled or disabled in the user's devices. Any way to find out USB debugging is enabled or disabled in android?